# PHP PDO Querying code from database doesn't show, only in source

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to query some data from my database but I have a section with raw php code that doesn't show up, only in the source as if it's trying to run.

I have the slashes stripped and I have it echoed under pre/code tags so I'm wondering as to why it won't show on the page.

### Database

```
id    name(VARCHAR)           code (LONGTEXT)
1         test         <?php echo /'hello world/'; ?>
```

### PHP File

```
<?php
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8', '$username', '$password');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name, codeOne FROM table_one WHERE id = :id');

            $stmt->bindParam(':id', '1');

            $stmt->execute();

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo $row['name'] . '<pre><code>'. stripslashes($row['codeOne']) .'</code></pre>';
                }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        };
    ?>
```

### What Everyone Sees

```
test
```

### View Source

```
test<pre><code><?php echo "Hello";?></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well just use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode your string, e.g.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<?php echo "Hello";?>');
```

What you see:

```
<?php echo "Hello";?>
```

Source code:

```
&lt;?php echo &quot;Hello&quot;;?&gt;
```

OR if you want to be really fancy you could use: [`highlight_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php), which also gives some nice color to your string:

```
echo highlight_string('<?php echo "Hello";?>', TRUE);
```

Comment: Yep. The unexecuted `<?php echo "Hello";?>` is treated as a HTML tag by the browser.

Comment: That solved it for me, thank you very much. I was following a guide and it didn't mention that.